# Sending emails by cron job vs straightaway , which technique is better?

Tags: php, multithreading, email, cron, codeigniter-3

It is a discussion question, I have no idea if there is other associated platform of SO to ask this type of question.

**Scenario:**

If admin or employees change the status of application, system needs to send email notification to user who created this application.

- Framework: Codeigniter
- Language: PHP

I am looking solution what could make it more faster.

**Solution 1**

send email straight away when status changes

Problem:  I think, this solution got some problems and will slow down the system as if status of 30 application change at once by employees then PHP will make the process slow. PHP will not run all requests simultaneously.

here is 2nd solution what i think could be better

**Solution 2**

save the email in database and setup cron job which runs after every minute and check if there is any email to send.

Problem :

if it would be setup to run after every minute and there are 30 or 50 emails in database to send then it could barely send 2 or 3 emails in 1 minute and then new cron job will call this function again and I am not sure how it will work then

Right now I am using solution 2 but wondering if someone could suggest which technique is better or if there is any 3rd solution.

Comment: This depends how you're sending the email. If you're rendering and sending individual emails directly it could take time, but if you're using a mail API of some sort, you can off-load a lot of the processing and the API call itself takes very little time. The big distinction here is if this process is user-initiated (e.g. clicking a button) or scheduled (e.g. every day at X time). Sending <100 emails shouldn't take a lot of time. It's for batches of >1000 that you'll have to shift processing to outside of your main application.

Comment: @tadman I am using my company email to send these email to user, using SMTP configuration, email could be 10 or could be 300 a day , it depends how many applications are received and how many time the status get changes for application

Comment: If you dump it on a local SMTP relay and let it take care of queueing, where [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org) does a great job here, it won't take long. If you're accessing an external SMTP server that requires authorization, it could be slow. Look at keeping the work PHP has to do to a minimum.

Comment: Instead of using a cron job, I'd use a message broker like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) for this. When the application status is changed, post a message to the broker. A separate application that's always running (`while (true)`) can register as a consumer and will immediately be notified when the broker receives a message. This application can then send the necessary emails. This app can be multithreaded to process multiple messages at a time or send multiple emails at a time. Or it can be started multiple times on separate machines for horizontal scaling, if necessary.

Comment: @coder you can use AWS queue for this. You have to push a data as key value (For e.g. {to:emai@domain.com, subject:name,content:XXXX}) and from your cron end, you have to consume this AWS queue and send a email.

Comment: Thank you every one, I will try RabbitMQ and see how it go